# UIMenuController fails to create a popup menu when Guided Access is on

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I noticed my app build with Xamarin.ios is failing while running with Guided Access enabled.

Specifically,UIMenuController failed to create a popup menu on long touch

```
UIMenuController uim = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController; 
//build menu items in list 
uim.MenuItems = list.ToArray (); 
//loc  is location in View - loc=_gr.LocationInView (this.View); 
//while _gr is a UILongPressGestureRecognizer  
uim.SetTargetRect (new RectangleF(loc.X, loc.Y, 1, 1), this.View); 
uim.SetMenuVisible (true, true);
```

I checked in debugger uim.MenuFrame is zero size frame

Otherwise the code works just fine if Guided Access is not enabled. I am running ios7 with app compiled with ios7 sdk. With ios6 and Guided Access enabled menu works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have  similar problem, did you get somewhere?

Comment: Latest Xamarin.iOS fixes the problem